# order by and file.exist() c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have file list which sorting by file length, and progress files.
The question is when progress takes a long time, some files in the list may be deleted, moved or can be changed, and I get the error
 
how can ı use order by and if file.exist() [check file is still there] method for this or any kind of solution?

```
var sort = from fn in filelist
           orderby new FileInfo(fn).Length ascending
           select fn;

foreach(string n in sort)
{
    //progress
}
```

Thanks

filelist has file's address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use File.Exists method this way :

```
   var sort = from fn in filelist
               where File.Exists(fn)
               orderby new FileInfo(fn).Length ascending
               select fn;
```

Comment: note that you should be able to write `var sort = filelist.Where(File.Exists).OrderBy(fn => new FileInfo(fn).Length)`

Comment: This won't help. As the questioner stated: processing might take a long time, during which files may be deleted. So the file could still exist while the sequence is enumerated in the foreach (somewhere deep inside: `Enumerator.MoveNext` and `Enumerator.Current`), if might be deleted after checking whether it exists.